# Local flows and diffeomorphism flow map

Tags: differential-geometry

In Loring Tu's book introduction to manifolds, the definition of a local flow, page 223-224 we have:

For a smooth vector field $X$ on $M$ and $p$ in $M$, there exists an open set $U$ of $p$ and an $\epsilon>0$ and a smooth map $\varphi: (-\epsilon,\epsilon)\times U \rightarrow M$ such that

$\varphi_t(q)$ is an integral curve of $X$ at $q$, for all $q\in U$.

$\varphi_{s}\circ \varphi_{t}=\varphi_{s+t}$ whenever both sides are defined.

This definition implies then that

The map $\varphi_t:U\rightarrow \varphi_{t}(U)$ is a diffeomorphism onto its image.

My question is why is $\varphi_{t}(U)$ a manifold? I think it should be open, but I don't see how that follows from the definitions.

Comment: Open subsets of manifolds are submanifolds. Diffeomorphisms map submanifolds to submanifolds.

Comment: @Didier $\varphi_{s}\circ \varphi_{t}=\varphi_{s+t}$ tells us that $\varphi_{t}$ is a bijection. Yes, $U$ is open in $M$. But why is $\varphi_{t}(U)$ open? The claim $\varphi_t$ is a diffeo onto image follows from giving image a smooth structure.

Comment: @Didier Ofcourse if $\varphi_s$ is a diffeomorphism then what you said obviously holds. That's not what i'm asking

Comment: There is a theorem from general topology that says if $U\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is homeomorphic to an open subset, it is an open subset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\mathcal{D}_t$ denote those points for which the flow is defined for time at least $t$ ($0$ to $t$ or $t$ to $0$ depending on the sign, not necessarily $-t$ to $t$). One can show that $\mathcal{D}_t$ is open. Together with $\phi_{s+t} = \phi_s\phi_t$, the map $\phi_t\colon\mathcal{D}_t\to\mathcal{D}_{-t}$ is a diffeomorphism. The $U$ in question is an open subset of $\mathcal{D}_t$, hence $\phi_t(U)$ is open in $M$.

Here's a sketch of why $\mathcal{D}_t$ is open. Pick a $p\in\mathcal{D}_t$ and look at its flow on $[0, t]$. This is compact and one can construct a neighbourhood $W$ of this curve where the flow is defined for some tiny $\delta$. Within this $W$ there's a smaller neighbourhood $W_1$ of $p$ on which it makes sense to move by $\delta$, $n$ times i.e., composing $\phi_\delta$ $n$ times (to see this, observe that I can move $2\delta$ units in $W\cap \phi_\delta^{-1}W$) where $n$ is chosen so that $n\delta>t$. So, $W_1\subseteq\mathcal{D}_t$.

A reference for the above is Warner's Foundations of Differential Manifolds and Lie Groups. Alternatively, as mentioned in the comments, since $\phi_t$ is a homeomorphism, by invariance of domain, the image of the open set $U$ is open.

Answer (score 0):

Assume that $\phi_0$ is identity map. Since $\phi_t$ is a smooth map, and $\phi_{-t}$ is the inverse of $\phi_t$ which is also a smooth map, we have that $\phi_t$ is a diffeomorphism and $\phi_t(U)$ is an open set. Hence $\phi_t(U)$ is a manifold by inducing charts of $M$ on $\phi_t(U)$.